# python pip install "mkl-fft" could not install

Tags: python, pip

I tried "pip install mkl-fft"
but could not finish.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
```

my env is

```
conda create -n myenv1 python=3.5
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

now pip ver is "20.1.1"

Further, I tried python 3.7.
I can`t install too.

do you have any Idea?
thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're not the only one that's seeing this issue.  From the [project's github page](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft), they actually direct to use a `conda install -c intel mkl_fft`.

Further it looks like there are multiple issues open for pip install problems. Here's [one](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft/issues/26), and [another](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft/issues/36). I would recommend trying the conda install first.