Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement contourpy==1.3.1
I'm conda to manage a python project, now I want to deploy my app to a linux machine.
ihave this Dockerfile :
FROM python:3.9-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "streamlit","run","main.py","--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

to generate requirements.txt i run pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
when I run docker compose build --no-cache I got this error :
18.69 ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.10
18.69 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement contourpy==1.3.1 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.1.0, c1, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1rc1, 1.2.1, 1.3.0)
18.69 ERROR: No matching distribution found for contourpy==1.3.1
24.04
24.04 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.3.1
24.04 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

and contourpy==1.3.1  is present in https://pypi.org/ any solution to this problem please ?
thnaks

Is there a reason why you are using python:3.9-slim ..? Just go for python:3.13-slim and the package will install.

i have update it to python:3.13-slim this time it gives :
89.05 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl_fft==1.3.10 (from versions: none)
94.39 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl_fft==1.3.10

mkl_fft is not in pypi, it's in Intel private repo.. see https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft for the right parameters to pip. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688075/python-pip-install-mkl-fft-could-not-install

It's in the error message: " 1.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.10"

do you have any idea please how i can install it using dockerfile, should I place it after RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt and I remove it from requirements.txt ?

@vaizki what could be the solution please ? I'm not a python expert actually if you could help please .

According to pypi, contourpty 1.3.1 requires Python version 3.10 (or later):

Unless you have a specific reason to use an older version of Python, it's a good idea to base your container images on the latest release. It looks like contourpy versions earlier than 1.3.1 will work with Python 3.9.

thanks for your time, i have update it to python:3.13-slim this time it gives : 89.05 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl_fft==1.3.10 (from versions: none) 94.39 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl_fft==1.3.10

There are apparently known problems trying to pip install the mkl_fft package. I'm not familiar with the package and can't provide guidance here.

do you have any idea please how i can install it using dockerfile, should I place it after RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt and I remove it from requirements.txt ?

The mkl_fft library typically supports stable Python versions. You should downgrade your python version such as

python:3.11-slim
python:3.12-slim

By using these version the command should work!
pip install mkl-fft


thanks for your time, even if I downgrad the version I got the same error, because mkl_fft is not in pypi anymore ..I have no idea how to resolve this problem.

Oh, You can try to install it directly from Github

any idea how I do this please ?

To install this library directly from GitHub you can execute this command
pip install git+https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git

is there a way to specify the version of mkl ?

Yes you can specify release versions using the '@version' at the end of the command. For example
pip install git+https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git@v1.3.0
And one thing I forgot to mention is that you need to install 'GIT' as it is not present in docker by default. To do that add this in your docker file
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ok, then I need to remove them from the requirements.txt ? and what should I run first, RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt or RUN git+github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft.git@v1.3.0 ?

@innov-aphp https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/ its available. What is the architecture of your system x64 or arm?

I'm trying to build a docker image from windows labtop
